# Sending password to mobile

Tags: php

I am using the below code to send password to mobile and the code doesn't seems to work.
Really appreciate  any help on this.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $phone = "select mobno from registration where username='" . $_GET['id'] . "' ";
    $mailto = "select regemail from registration where username='" . $_GET['id'] . "' ";
    $subject = "passcode";
    mail($mailto, $subject, $);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Code Sent Successfully");</script>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=",log.php">';
}
```

Comment: Please Please never ever send a password to anybody.

Comment: Please, never use the get parameter directly in the query..

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your code like this:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $phone = mysql_query("SELECT mobno FROM registration WHERE username='" . $_GET['id'] . "' ; ");
    $mailto = mysql_query("SELECT regemail FROM registration WHERE username='" . $_GET['id'] . "' ; ");
    $subject = "passcode";
    mail($mailto, $subject, $phone);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Code Sent Successfully");</script>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0,log.php">';
}
```

Don't forget to connect to your mySQL-Database at the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
/* DB connection */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}


if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $sql = 'SELECT mobno,regemail FROM registration WHERE username=:user'; // I suspect this should be id=:user due to $_GET['id'] and not $_GET['username']
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':user' => $_GET['id']));
    $data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $phone = $data['mobno'];
    $mailto = $data['regemail'];
    $subject = "passcode";

    mail($mailto, $subject, $phone);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Code Sent Successfully");</script>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=",log.php">';
}
```

You may find the php manual on PDO helpful http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php